# Java store Double in Integer[]

Tags: java

I want to store a Double in a Integer Array and be able to read the Double again, like:

`int[2] doubleToIntArr(double)`

`double intArrToDouble(int[2])`

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Yes. What have you done?

Comment: @Tunaki , well obviously I don't know how to do it. That's why I am asking...

Comment: There are multiple ways to store a `Double` as 2 integers depending on why you want to do that in the first place

Comment: as a more dirty dirty option you could create a string out of this two int´s and use `Double.parseDouble(String);`.

Comment: does this have anything to do with transporting the double over a network protocol, or storing it in a file?

Comment: @Alnitak No I want to save it in a int[]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way:

1. Use `Double.doubleToLongBits(double)` to turn the `double` into a `long`.
2. Use shifting and masking to extract the high and low parts of the `long`, and store them in the `int[]` (or `Integer[]`).

(There are other ways to implement this, but if you are concerned about performance, this is probably the most efficient way to do it in pure Java.)

---

Note that this transformation is not computationally useful.  It is difficult to do anything computationally meaningful with the pair of `int` values apart from turning them back into a `double`.

Comment: Thanks, I should have come up with the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

```
  double d = 100;
  long l = Double.doubleToLongBits(d);
  int i1 = (int)(l >> 32);
  int i2 = (int)l;

  double d2 = Double.longBitsToDouble(((long)i1 << 32) | (i2&0xFFFFFFFFL));
  System.out.println(d2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`java.nio.ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class has methods that allow you to read and write standard data types to or from a byte array.

You should be able to use that to write your `Double`, and then read out two `ints`, e.g.

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
buf.putDouble(d);
int i1 = buf.getInt(0);
int i2 = buf.getInt(4);
```